# When using csv.writer to write a specific column to a new file, the loop is iterating over every character

Tags: python

Ok, so I am new to programming in general and absolutely new to Python. I'm starting to build my first project which basically will go get CSV files of state data and then pull from each file to create a single file. Anyway, to start I want to just get it to work with one file.

```
import csv

with open('Active_Iowa_Business_Entities.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    with open('new_names_now.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(str(line[2]))
```

My problem is, while I have figured out how to get the specific column I want the loop seems to be iterating over each letter in that column. So instead of getting this:

REVISED DOMESTIC NON-PROFIT

I am getting this:

R,E,V,I,S,E,D, ,D,O,M,E,S,T,I,C, ,N,O,N,-,P,R,O,F,I,T

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csv.writer.writerow` takes an iterable as argument, where each element of the iterable is a value you want to write in your line, so here, you'd write:

```
csv_writer.writerow((str(line[2]),))
```

Where `(str(line[2]),)` is a tuple containing only the element you want to write.

Comment: And just like that, my problem is solved. Thank you!